# How to change layout of node add/edit form with Display Suite?

Tags: nodes, forms, theming, display-suite

Is there a way to use Display Suites to change a Layout for a Node Edit/Add form?
i.e. form at: .../node/add/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is possible yes. Display Suite contains a submodule called 'Display Suite Forms' which allows you then to select a layout and move the fields around in that layout.

Note that it's impossible though to move the individual elements in the vertical tabs. That will always remain the same and will rendered at the bottom of the layout.

Comment: when you say it is impossible to move _individual_ elements in the vertical tabs, does that imply one can move the whole vertical tabs container using ds? If so, how?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the vertical tabs section will always render at the bottom of the form. I was trying to move it, and couldn't figure out what I was not doing correctly.

Comment: You can always use the [Field group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module to create another set of vertical tabs. If you get really crazy, you could move everything from the default vertical tabs into those and then place anything on the form anywhere you want :-p I believe the [Renderable Elements](https://drupal.org/project/rel) module would make that possible.

Comment: I spent a while trying to change the content edit form with display suite but this shows it was a dead-end.

Comment: In Drupal 8 use the Field Layout module from core instead. Display Suite Form submodule was removed from the 8.x branch of DS because of that.